# Make google drive fmt stream map stream links works when load on server

Tags: php, stream, google-drive-api

When I attempt to access video links on my google drive via my server, using via fmt map, they are not working on the client side  because of ip tracking.

> I have researched all stackoverfow similar topics but there is no solution.

you can check this for reference :

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/google-get-video-fmt-stream-map

I know it's all about ip adresse so how some people make this works ?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not the final solution but it can hopefully bring some new info.

I have tried two ways already. One PHP from the site you suggested and one Javascript.

**PHP** gives me a link that has similar parameters as a working link that I got from browser developer tools so it could work. The problem as you say is IP because through PHP there is IP of the server and the rest is generated upon that. So I have tried to stream it through PHP to use the same IP address by readfile()

```
/*code follows code from the link*/
$gdrive = new gdrive;
$drive_link = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=videoID';
$gdrive->getLink($drive_link);

$theFile = json_decode( $gdrive->getSources() , true );
//echo $theFile[0]['src'];
/*header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length:'.filesize($theFile[0]['src']));*/

readfile($theFile[0]['src']);
```

but it doesn't work anyway. I don't know if that is right way or if there is another google security obstacle?

From **Javascript**, when trying to request docs.google.com/get_video_info or drive.google.com/file/d/videoID/view, it gives me a CORS Cross-Origin error (in Web Console) that I can't resolve.